# How to set specific attributes of a dictionary to []

Tags: python, dictionary

Let us imagine the following dictionary

```
dictionary = {
    "key1": {
         "value": [1, 3, 5],
     },

    "key2": {
         "value": [1, 2, -1],
     },
}
```

Is it possible to set all the `"values"` to `[]` without iterating over the dictionary keys? I want something like `dictionary[]["value"]=[]` such that all "value" attributes are set to `[]`. But that doesn't work.

Comment: No, it isn't possible.

Comment: You don't need to iterate over the keys. Iterating over the values is enough to get the job done.

Comment: It might be helpful to give some *context* - why do you think you want this? As well as being fragile, the answer you've accepted is going to be pretty inefficient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you need to avoid iteration, here is a **little hacky** way of solving the case.

Convert dictionary to string, replace and then back to dictionary:

```
import re, ast

dictionary = {
    "key1": {
         "value": [1, 3, 5],
     },

    "key2": {
         "value": [1, 2, -1],
     },
}

print(ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r'\[.*?\]', '[]', str(dictionary))))
# {'key1': {'value': []}, 'key2': {'value': []}}
```

Comment: "A little". Right :) +1

Comment: How does this avoid iteration? You might not be writing a for loop, but how do you think the repr gets generated? Also it's pretty fragile.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I suppose there is no iteration. Seriously, I'm not sure how repr is generated. Could you shed some light on it?

Comment: Well, there are two ways to implement repr: 1) It iterates over the keys and values of the dict and converts them to strings, or 2) It's magic.

Comment: We thank you for this witchcraft you have shared with us

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a different tack here. Your question is a little misinformed. The implication is that it's "better" to avoid iterating dictionary keys. As mentioned, you can iterate over dictionary values. But, since internally Python [stores dictionaries via two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/9209546), iteration is unavoidable.

Returning to your core question:

> I want something like `dictionary[]["value"]=[]` such that all "value"
>   attributes are set to `[]`.

Just use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {k: defaultdict(list) for k in dictionary}

print(d['key1']['value'])  # []
print(d['key2']['value'])  # []
```

For the dictionary structure you have defined, this will certainly be more efficient than string conversion via `repr` + regex substitution.

If you insist on explicitly setting keys, you can avoid `defaultdict` at the cost of an inner dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {k: {i: [] for i in v} for k, v in dictionary.items()}

{'key1': {'value': []}, 'key2': {'value': []}}
```